# Efficient way to work with python and numpy for simple to medium calculations

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

Assume a few functions called many times.  These functions do something such as multiply, divide, add, on a 3d vector (a 1x3 array).

Given:

```
import numpy as np
import math
x = [0,1,2]
y = [3,2,1]
a = 1.2
```

Based on my testing, it is faster for python math library to do:

```
math.sin(a)
```

than for numpy to do:

```
np.sin(a)
```

Additionally, simple algorithms such as normalization are faster with python than np.linalg.norm using the method discussed in [this conversation](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/848926).

Now if we add a bit of complexity to the data, such as doing matrix multiplication for 3d, where we have a rotation matrix of 3x3 that is then multiplied by another matrix and transposed, numpy starts to gain the advantage.

Currently, doing operations such as:

```
L = math.sqrt(V[0] * V[0] + V[1] * V[1] + V[2] * V[2]) 
V = (V[0] / L, V[1] / L, V[2] / L)
```

are much faster when called repeatedly (I assume from no overhead in creating the numpy array).

However, in order to use the numpy matrix functions, the array needs to be numpy.  Using np.asarray() has significant overhead, which makes the efficiency border between not using numpy at all, accepting the overhead of creating the array, or accepting the efficiency of numpy math functions on scalars and only using numpy.

Of course I can try out all of these methods, but in a large algorithm, the possible combinations are too much.  Is there any strategy to efficiently switch between python and numpy in this situation?

EDIT:
From some comments, it seems the question is not clear enough.  I understand numpy is more efficient with big sets, which is why this question exists.  The algorithm is NOT ONLY calculating sine.  The following code might make it easier to understand:

```
x = [2,1,2]
math.sin(x[0])
L = math.sqrt(x[0] * x[0] + x[1] * x[1] + x[2] * x[2]) 
V = (x[0] / L, x[1] / L, x[2] / L)
math.sin(V[0])
#Do something else here
```

Comment: How did you compare execution speed? If you used vectorization (as you always should with numpy, i.e. instead of running `np.sin(a)` a few thousand times, run `np.sin(np.repeat(1.2, 1000))` once) I doubt it's slower than Python's own `math`.

Comment: @Phillip I used timeit,

Comment: timeit.timeit('import numpy as np;import math;math.sin(234.2343),100000') and switch between math.sin and np.sin

Comment: That's not a good comparison. See e.g. [here on vectorization](http://quantess.net/2013/09/30/vectorization-magic-for-your-computations/)

Comment: @Phillip Im not seeing your point about vectorization and why timeit is not a good comparison, can you elaborate

Comment: You should never call `numpy.sin` 100k times in a loop on independent arguments. But that is what your test does. The numpy doc explicitly states that Python loops should be avoided and replaced with vectorized code if one wants speed.

Comment: @Phillip its not possible to do that, which is a main motivation for the question.

Comment: Haven't you answered your own question?  If you are only working with a few numbers there's no need to incur the `ndarray` overhead.  I'm tempted to suggest closing this for being too vague and open ended.

Comment: @hpaulj , the numbers are small, but there are many calculations, as in, the edit i added is run many times. The question is what the most efficient way to switch from numpy to not.  I dont think it is too broad, it is specifically how to handle the edge case where overhead is close to comp. speed.  Is there a method for working between the two.

Comment: For example, it is faster to convert the list to a numpy array and then run a sine operation than it is to pass sine the list and then have it return the numpy value

Comment: ... and as I mention in my question, the issue is when doing many of these small calculations, and then needing to do a matrix operation, in which numpy is faster, but then this requires switching the list to an array, which takes time.  In my case the first few combinations I tried are similar, so I was curious if others have a more productive way of finding the balance than randomly testing combinations

Comment: Your example doesn't make clear at all why you can't vectorize your calculation. I'd suggest that you update your question with the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score -1):

When working with single values, and small arrays, the `np.array` overhead certainly slows things down compared to using the `math.` equivalents.  But with many values, the array approach quickly becomes better.

For example in `Ipython` I can time `sin` for 50 values:

```
In [444]: %%timeit x=np.arange(50)
np.sin(x)
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.5 us per loop

In [445]: %%timeit x=range(50)
[math.sin(i) for i in x] 
100000 loops, best of 3: 18.1 us per loop
```

Your `V` calculation is 20x faster than

```
Va=Va/math.sqrt((Va*Va).sum())
```

But if I do that on 20 sets of values, the times are about equal.  And I don't have to change the expression to handle `Va=np.ones((20,3), float)`.  To time your `V` I had to wrap it in a function and time `[foo(i) for i in V]`.

You might even gain more speed by doing the indexing only once, e.g.

```
v1, v2, v3 = V
L = math.sqrt(v1*v1+ v2*v2+v3*v3)
V = (v1/L, v2/L, v3/L)
```

I'd expect more gain when using arrays than lists.